# WP plugin(s) that will easily voting up/down rows in a list (not at post level)

Tags: wordpress

In my WP site I have a table (currently formidable forms entries but not attached) that contains only a couple of fields (stem and word). I want users of the site to be able to see a list of all the "words" on a single page (or actually paging through say 25 at a time of the list which is several hundred rows) and be able to click to vote up/down each entry accordingly. I've tried a number of vote/like plugins but these always work only at the post level and I don't want users to have to click into the post itself just to be able to vote. Anything out there that does this? TIA, M

Comment: So you want to be able to vote on a post, on the archive? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't mind if the content is a post or some other content object in the system - essentially it is just a word/phrase. The vote would indeed apply to that post/content but voters should not need to click into that content as a separate page access but should be able to vote from a list of words shown as an index IYSWIM. Also downvoting is needed as well as upvoting ;)

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand, but I will do my best, to give you and idea.. - there is probably a million ways of doing this - but it does not seem like you mind coding a bit.

Comment: One way to do it - Is to use ACF and create a single page template. with ACF you then add a repeater to your page, with to inputs : A text field (for the word/phrase) and a number field (for the vote).

Comment: you then code your template, to use the ACF fields, and create a function that can increase and decrase the vote number

Comment: then you can sort the repeater according to the votes.

Comment: Yes, I don't mind doing a bit of code but want to keep it as simple as poss as the WP site is just for managing the design of an actual app which is where I want my coding energy to go ;)

Comment: OK have the ACF and the custom template and I can enter row data in the admin backend and display it in the front end - it's a decent start and a useful plugin for wider use but I'd also like to a) allow the end users to update the rating value - how would that find it's way to getting updated? b) I'd like them to be able to add new rows and c) I'd like to sort the rows by rating or keyword ;)

Comment: So everything you need now, should be here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#functions  - add_sub_row(), update_sub_row() etc. is all functions for managing the repeater. - if you want to have it update without a page refresh, i would suggest doing it with AJAX.

Comment: To sort by rating or keyword - you just sort the repeater : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/

Comment: and by the way - just saw that repeater is an addon : found here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

Comment: That's fine - it's a quality plugin so I went Pro on it ;)

Comment: I basically can't imagine my life without it - use it for all sites, since the possibilities  are near limitless. I puzzle why something like this isn't in the core. Hope you get it to work man

Comment: Those links above are giving me 503s right now though...

Comment: Should be up again, just got in